# Optional parameter const reference reassignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I know this isn't possible as I am breaking the heart of the const constract, I am not allowed to modify the object in any way, but how else do I optionally pass a parameter as reference?

Suppose I have an error code struct and some member function I optionally want to check the error code of

```
struct my_error_code {
    int val;
    std::string message;
};


struct my_complicated_obj {
    /* Compiles fine, understandbly, ec is not optional*/
    void do_stuff(/*params,*/my_error_code& ec){
        ec = {0x10, "Something went wrong"};
        return;
    }

    void do_stuff_optionally(/*params,*/ const my_error_code& ec= {}){
        /* There is no overload of assignment or constructos I can trick into allowing this.. */
        ec = {0x20, "Something is wrong."};
        return;
    }

};
```

In the above `do_stuff_optionally` obviously won't compile. The solution I know of then is to do

```
my_error_code& my_error_code_default(){
    static my_error_code ec = {0, "No Error"};
    return ec;
}
void do_stuff_optionally_not_so_very_clean(/*params,*/ my_error_code& ec = my_error_code_default()){
        ec = {0x11, "Something went wrong."};
    }
```

But as the name implies this isn't very clean, to keep a global object (essentially) just so I can use my type as an optional mutable parameter by reference.

I tried looking into how boost does this with `boost::system::error_code` and I could not find any static object there, so how does boost do this? What is the clean approach?

Comment: I you're stuck with C++11 there is `boost::optional`.  You could also just pass by pointer and default to `nullptr`.

Comment: Just use some wrapper. Writing `optional<T &>` storing pointer internally is trivial.

Comment: Except as a generic wrapper you can't easily overload `operator .`, so it ends up looking like a pointer anyway.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to ignore an error, anyway?

Comment: Extending a library, there is no error code now, and I wan't to ease this in instead of breaking the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write out the overload by hand:

```
void do_stuff_optionally(/*params,*/ my_error_code& ec);

void do_stuff_optionally(/*params */) {
    my_error_code ec;
    do_stuff_optionally(/*params,*/ ec);
}
```

That said, if your function isn't returning anything, you could just return the error code directly which is cleaner. If it is returning something else, you could return either the object or your error code with a `boost::variant`.

Finally, you should be aware, since you are using boost, that boost often uses this overloading convention with error code passed in by reference vs not, to mean: if you don't pass in an error code, then throw to indicate an error. You are using the same convention to mean (afaics) ignore the error, which can be a bit risky (I think).

Comment: Wasn't me, and I appreciate your answer, but overloading is not an option, and the return type may not be void.

Comment: @arynaq Err, why is overloading not an option? You're going to have to give more details. And my answer isn't affected in any significant way if the return type isn't void; you can simply do `return do_stuff_optionall(/*parms,*/, ec)`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `const`, and use a pointer instead of a reference:

```
struct my_complicated_obj {
    void do_stuff(/*params,*/my_error_code& ec){
        do_stuff_optionally(/*params,*/ &ec);
    }

    void do_stuff_optionally(/*params,*/ my_error_code *ec = nullptr){
        if (ec)
            *ec = {0x20, "Something is wrong."};
    }
};
```

Let the caller decide whether it wants the error code or not.